# convert python timestamp into minutes using JavaScript react

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, timestamp

I'm working on a project using python(3.7) and React in which I'm getting a `timestamp` from python and need to display it inside `react component` and need to display it as `minutes`.

Here's what I tried:

```
{Math.round((new Date().getTime() - new Date(message.timestamp).getTime())/60000)} minutes ago
```

it displayed as:

```
NaN minutes ago
```

If I display it as:

```
{message.timestamp}
```

then it returns:

```
2019-04-09 13:01:22.036902+00:00
```

So, how can I display only minutes from that `timestamp`?

Comment: Maybe you want to try with ``moment.js``?

Comment: Your "timestamp" is of type `String` (ISO formatting). You need to parse it into a `Date`. Passing a string into the `Date` constructor creates an invalid `Date` object, that's why your calculation fails to `NaN`.

Comment: i copied your code and replaced `{message.timestamp}` with : `2019-04-09 13:01:22.036902+00:00`: https://jsfiddle.net/cwfeo517/ and it works

Comment: I'm guessing you cannot change the python code and simply use ```.minute``` on the datetime object ? Example : ```datetime.now().minute```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) library and format your string as you want

```js
const a = "2019-04-09 13:01:22.036902+00:00"
console.log(moment(a).format('hh:mm A'))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
```

Using `Date`

```js
var a = new Date("2019-04-09 13:01:22.036902+00:00")


a.getMinutes()

console.log("hours:"+a.getHours(),"minutes:"+a.getMinutes())
```

As per comment If your looking for difference between two timestamps then

```js
const timediff= moment().diff(moment("2019-04-09 13:01:22.036902+00:00"),'minutes')


console.log('timediff',timediff)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is not what the OP was asking for due to he wants to evaluate a difference between two dates

Comment: as he mentioned the in question `how can I display only minutes from that timestamp` so elaborated how to display hours and minutes. But now updated both

Comment: i am willing to vote this up but there is still no diff using native Date API :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try

{Math.round((new Date().getTime() - Date.parse(String(message.timestamp)))/60000)} minutes ago

I think that should work